# How to dispatch and listen event on js class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developing basic word game.

I have a js class: word.ts
and react project.

This is my class

```
class WordGame {
  words: string[]
  gameOver: boolean
  usedWords: string[]
  whoseTurn: 'player' | 'computer' | 'none'
  activeWord: string


  constructor(wordList: string[]) {
    this.words = wordList
    this.gameOver = false
    this.usedWords = []
    this.whoseTurn = 'none'
    this.activeWord = ''
  }

  private updateActiveWord(word: string) {
    this.activeWord = word.toLowerCase()
    //----> I want to dispatch event on this step <----

  }
}
```

How to dispatch event after update ***this.activeWord***. And how to listen from react component.

Comment: You can create a EventEmitter class, try this https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-your-own-event-emitter-in-javascript-fbd5db2447c4

Comment: Attach `dispatch` to the appropriate event handler of your component.